# Solve $\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) < 0$ for x?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I'm a little rusty w/ inequalities. I know the answer is $x >2$.

$$\cos\frac{\pi}{x} < 0 \implies \frac{\pi}{x} < \cos^{-1}0$$
$$\implies \frac{\pi}{x} < \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\implies 2\pi<x\pi$$
$$\implies x<2$$

Does the inequality switch when you take the inverse trig. function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is $\cos t<0?$ In $\displaystyle\left(\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi} 2\right)$ if you are working on $[0,2\pi).$ So, to solve your question you need to solve

$$\frac\pi 2<\frac \pi x<\frac{3\pi} 2.$$

Note that $\cos $ is $2\pi$-periodic. So if you don't have any restriction on the value of $x$ you have to consider other intervals, as $$\frac{5\pi} 2<\frac \pi x<\frac{7\pi} 2.$$

Note that $\cos 0=1>0=\cos \frac \pi 2.$ However $0<\frac\pi 2.$ That's because $$\arccos:[-1,1]\to [0,\pi]$$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint **

$x\mapsto \cos(x)$ is even .let $x\neq 0$

$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{x})<0 \iff$$
$$\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi<\frac{\pi}{x}<\frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi$$

$$\iff   \frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}+2k} <x<\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+2k}$$

for $k\geq 0$, and

$$\iff \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+2k}<x<\frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}+2k}$$
for $k<0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, the inequality does not switch when you take the inverse trig. function, you flipped it by accident on the last step when you shouldn't have.